# How to make text start/end at a node location in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, nodes, text

I'm trying to make a Figure in tikz, I would the labels "u[i,J]" and "u[I,J]" to keep certain distance from his corresponding arrows, based on labelDist parameter.

As an example, is it possible to make the text "u[i,J]" to end at his corresponding node??, I thought right alignment could do the trick, but it seems to have another effect. In this case it seems simple for me to define a node where the text ends and the text label adjust automatically to be written to the left of the node location, is there another simple way to accomplish my objective?

I would also like to keep the distance from the text and the arrow defined based on labelDist parameter for aesthetic reasons.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cellSize}{2}
\newcommand{\arrowSize}{0.4}
\newcommand{\nodeRadius}{0.125}
\newcommand{\labelDist}{0.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]        
% P grid

\draw (0,0)--(\cellSize,0)--(\cellSize,\cellSize)--(0,\cellSize)--cycle;
\draw (0.5*\cellSize,0.5*\cellSize) circle [radius = \nodeRadius];

% Labels


\draw[->] (-0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize)--(0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize);
\node[align=right] at (-0.5*\arrowSize-\labelDist,0.5*\cellSize) {u[i,J]};


\draw[->] (\cellSize-0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize)--(\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize);
\node[align=left] at (\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize+\labelDist,0.5*\cellSize) {u[i+1,J]};

\draw[->] (0.5*\cellSize,-0.5*\arrowSize)--(0.5*\cellSize,0.5*\arrowSize);
\node at (0.5*\cellSize,-0.5*\arrowSize-\labelDist) {v[I,j]};

\draw[->] (0.5*\cellSize,\cellSize-0.5*\arrowSize)--(0.5*\cellSize,\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize);
\node at (0.5*\cellSize,\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize+\labelDist) {v[I,j+1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are other options like` [above, sloped, pos=0.8]` for adding labels to arrows, but that seems to not be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but are you looking for this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cellSize}{2}
\newcommand{\arrowSize}{0.4}
\newcommand{\nodeRadius}{0.125}
\newcommand{\labelDist}{0.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]        
% P grid

\draw (0,0)--(\cellSize,0)--(\cellSize,\cellSize)--(0,\cellSize)--cycle;
\draw (0.5*\cellSize,0.5*\cellSize) circle [radius = \nodeRadius];

% Labels


\draw[->] (-0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize)node[left]  {u[i,J]} 
--(0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize);


\draw[->] (\cellSize-0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize)
--(\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize,0.5*\cellSize) node[right]{u[i+1,J]};

\draw[->] (0.5*\cellSize,-0.5*\arrowSize)node[below]{v[I,j]}
--(0.5*\cellSize,0.5*\arrowSize);

\draw[->] (0.5*\cellSize,\cellSize-0.5*\arrowSize)--(0.5*\cellSize,\cellSize+0.5*\arrowSize)
node[above]{v[I,j+1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yeah what you provided is what I was looking for. Can I ask why \node[left] is between the points that define the arrow and \node[right] at the end?

Comment: @FranciscoAngel This is how Ti*k*Z path construction works. You say `\draw <coordinate>` and then what Ti*k*Z should do with the coordinate. In this example I say "draw coordinate at its left" and then "draw a line to the next coordinate". When you arrive at the coordinate, you can put another node (or whatever).